# android phone + mobile network + chromecast

Tags: mobile-data, chromecast

I have unlimited mobile data on my phone. but i want to cast to the chromecast. But i cant find a way to do that using my current knowledge.

the setup require .
data streaming using mobile data in mobile
and casting using wifi from mobile.

i tried to connect to guest mode. but that allows only limited apps allowed by chromecast to cast to the device.

is there anyother options.

Comment: My guess is that you could create a mobile hotspot and connect the chromecast to that. If that doesn't work I think you're stuck using just the limited functionality.

Comment: @cascer1 i tried that. but the issue in the same mobile cant be used for hotspot :(. chromecast wont support

Answer (score 0):

Chromecast can only use one network at a time. You need to set your phone up as a hotspot then using the google cast app connect your chromecast to the mobile network.

Comment: i am looking for option in android. not chromecast. There is a guest mode in chromecast. that should allow me to do what i want. but Guest mode only allows chromecast apps to cast to it.

Comment: @NaveenBabu once the chromecast is connected to your phone's network it should work fine. You will need to make it switch from its current network though

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by having 2 phone + chrome cast

**Data mobile + hotspot** 
1st mobile with unlimited internet in mobile data + wifi hotspot

**connected to the 1st mobile hotspot are:**
2nd mobile just to play content needed for sharing to chromecast.
and the chromecast.